# Load Unity mappings from an XML File

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I would like to be able to load the following into Unity:

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<ClientRegistrationVM, ClientRegistrationVMDesign>();
```

By loading it via an XML File.

Here would be some psudo code of what I would like to have happen.

```
FileStream unityMappings = new FileStream(@".\UnityMappings.xml", FileMode.Open)
UnityContainer.CreateFromXML(unityMappings);
unityMappings.Dispose();
```

And the UnityMappings.xml file would contain the mappings and the dlls that the types are in.

Is what I want even possible with Unity?  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: @SebastianWeber - I have "heard of Google" (a bit insulting in the tone there).  I did Google it.  I just did not know the right phrase.  Try to google "unity ioc from file"  The only relevant hit you will get is my question (which of course was not there when I googled).

Comment: [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/Sharpoverride/archive/2009/08/20/ioc-containers-in-.net-part-6-unity-container.aspx) is the 5th result on the first page of Google's result list using your search terms. As it shows a sample configuration for Unity using XML I consider it a relevant result.

Comment: @SebastianWeber - I did not see that.  But even so that uses App.Config.  I needed a free standing xml file (as provided by nemesv).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use XML configuration with Unity, you can even mix the design time config (XML) and runtime (code) configuration.

However the [Design-Time Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935(v=pandp.20)) uses the `UnityConfigurationSection` and the config loading is only supported through this so you need to do a little more work if you want to have the config in different (e.g. not app.config or web.config) file.

Luckily you can find a sample in the documentation under: [Loading the Configuration from Alternative Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#_Loading_the_Configuration)  section:

```cs
using System.Configuration;

var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "unity.config" };

Configuration configuration =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,                  
                                                    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("unity");

var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration(unitySection);
```